# How to use SQL procedure to generate a report for the procedure

Tags: postgresql, procedure

I am on Postgres SQL and am trying to write a procedure where, I can get the `name` from tableA and then loop over that `name` value and use it in another join query to get the results.
The aim of this procedure is to generate some kind of reports to look at or to generate the table rows and export them later to some csvformat.

This is how my function  goes.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION loop_names2()
RETURNS text AS $$
DECLARE
    name_row RECORD;
BEGIN
        -- Select names from table
        FOR name_row IN select name from TableA LOOP
            SELECT tc.time,tc.index,ta.name,tb.value FROM TableB as tb
            inner join TableC as tc on kpii.id = kpir.index_id
            inner join TableA as ta on kpic.id = kpir.kpi_id
            where ta.name = 'name_row.name';
        END LOOP;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

When I run it using CALL process_report(), the error message that I get is

```
ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
HINT:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function loop_names2() line 6 at SQL statement
SQL state: 42601
```

how should I change my procedure, to get the table rows and generate a report out of it.

Comment: [asked hundreds of times already](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[postgresql]+query+has+no+destination+for+result+data) If you want to return a result use a function, not a procedure

Comment: Procedures only returns data using `IN OUT` and using type cursor

Comment: Even if you switch to using a function instead of a procedure you will get the same error as the `SELECT tc.time,tc.index, ...` query has(per the error message) no destination for it's output. See [Returning from function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING) for your options.

Comment: edited the question as per suggestions to use functions.

Comment: You still are not actually returning anything. Read the link I posted in my previous comment.

Comment: yes the link helped, thank you, I was able to write and use my function